# VHDL small error when using a conditional signal assignment (when...else)

Tags: syntax-error, conditional-statements, vhdl

I'm currently working on a component that will perform addition or subtraction, depending on the user input. Right now, I am working on a process that handles the assignment of values to the internal signals which will be used by the internal components I am using. One problem that comes up is in the line when I'm assigning b_in with either the input b or the 2's complement of the input b. Two errors show up:

> Error: COMP96_0015: addsub_16.vhd : (85, 17): ';' expected.
>   Error: COMP96_0046: addsub_16.vhd : (85, 41): Sequential statement expected.
>   The errors all reference to the line
>   b_in <= (b) when add_sub = '0' else (b_2scomp);
>   However when I placed this outside the process, no error occurred; only when it's inside the process. Can someone please help me why this is and what I can do to solve it?

In addition, I know that normally port mapping is done between the architecture declaration and the begin statement of the architecture. The reason I placed them after the process is because I needed to make sure that b_in has the right signal before the other components can use it. I don't know if this is the right way to do it, but I hope it is. This is just in case you guys are wondering why I'm dong it like this. Thanks

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.all;  
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.all;

entity addsub_16 is
     port(
         c_in : in STD_LOGIC; 
         enable : in std_logic;
         reset : in std_logic;
         clk : in std_logic;
         add_sub : in STD_LOGIC;
         a : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
         b : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0);
         c_out : out STD_LOGIC;
         result : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 downto 0)
         );
end addsub_16;

architecture addsub_16 of addsub_16 is 

--Signal declarations to hold internal vectors a, b g, p, and carry
signal a_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);        --Holds input a
signal b_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);        --Holds input b if add_sub = 0. Otherwise, holds b_2scomp
signal b_2scomp : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);    --Holds the 2s complement of b
signal prop_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);     --Holds the propagate signals from CLAs
signal gen_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);      --Holds the generate signals from CLAs
signal carry_in : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);    --Holds the carry signal from carry_logic 
signal temp_result : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0); --Holds the temporary result to be driven out

--Component declarations 
component cla_4bit
    port (
        a, b : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
        gen, prop : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
end component;

component carry_logic
    port (
        g, p : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        c_in : in std_logic;
        carry : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        c_out : out std_logic
    ); 
end component;

--Actual behavior of module
begin   

--b_in <= (b) when add_sub = '0' else (b_2scomp);

    process (clk, reset)
    begin 
        if reset = '0' then                 --At reset, everything is 0
            a_in <= (others => '0');
            b_in <= (others => '0');
            b_2scomp <= (others => '0');
            temp_result <= (others => '0');

        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then       --Read in data to components on rising edge
            if enable = '1' then            --Only if enable is on
                a_in <= a;
                b_2scomp <= ((not b) + '1');
                b_in <= (b) when add_sub = '0' else (b_2scomp);             
            end if;
        elsif (falling_edge(clk)) then      --Drive out values on falling edge
            for i in 0 to 15 loop
                temp_result(i) <= a_in(i) xor b_in(i) xor carry_in(i);
            end loop;
            result <= temp_result;  
        end if;
    end process;

--portmapping of the components here. I don't think it'd be necessary to include them, but let me know if they are needed.
```

Comment: Turn on VHDL-2008 syntax in your compiler. Or rewrite the VHDL-2008 "when" assignment using an If/Then/Else statement.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up just rewriting it using if/then/else

Comment: "The reason I placed them after the process is because I needed to make sure that b_in has the right signal before the other components can use it."
Note that this is nonsense. VHDL is not executable code. It describes hardware. The order of concurrent statements (including component instances) is completely irrelevant, you are just describing how things are connected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ternary operator `.. when .. else ..` is not allowed inside a process block prior to VHDL-2008.

Solution 1: Write an ordinary `if .. then .. else .. end if` statement
Solution 2: Enable VHDL-2008 support in your tool chain
Solution 3: Write a function, lets say ite (if-then-else), which performs the ternary operation.